# SSIS multiple script components in one package seem to be using same scriptbuffer

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm new to script components in SSIS, so apologies if my question title doesn't make much sense.

I've been tasked with taking data(columns/records) from 18 csv files, doing a lookup against a database table and then writing records into a string (which will be an Oracle Insert statement), and each string written to a .txt file.

I have one package which consists of a script to create/clear data out of the .txt files, and then 18 data flow tasks which run after the script task has completed. Within each of those data flow tasks is a Flat File source, a Lookup and a Script component.

Script component code is basically identical for each one with a change of file name and columns being passed in:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\001_ADVICE.txt";
        string insertstatement = ("Insert into MAT.ADVICE VALUES ("
            + Row.MASEQNO + "," + Row.MACREATEDATE + ",'" + Row.MACREATEBY + "','" + Row.MAMACCASEID + "'," + Row.MAVERSION + ",'" + Row.MAJUSTREPAYMETHOD + "','" 
            + Row.MAJUSTTERM + "','" + Row.MAJUSTSCHTYPE + "','" + Row.MAJUSTSCHDURATION + "','" + Row.MAJUSTERC + "','" + Row.MAJUSTFEES + "','" + Row.MAJUSTOTHFEATURES 
            + "','" + Row.MAJUSTOTHNOTES + "'," + Row.MACHANGEDATE + ",'" + Row.MACHANGEBY + "'," + Row.MASUITLETTERPRINTED + ",'" + Row.MAREVIEWUSER 
            + "'," + Row.MAREVIEWDATE + ",'" + Row.MAREVIEWFLAG + "','" + Row.MAREVIEWRESULT + "','" + Row.MAREVIEWNOTE + "','" + Row.MAREVIEWCONF
            + "','" + Row.MASPELLREVIEWUSER + "'," + Row.MASPELLREVIEWDATE + ",'" + Row.MASPELLREVIEWRESULT + "','" + Row.MASPELLREVIEWNOTE
            + "','" + Row.MASPELLREVIEWCONF + "','" + Row.MAJUSTUSER + "," + Row.MAREJDATE + ",'" + Row.MAVALISSUE + "','" + Row.MAADVICESTATUS + "');" + Environment.NewLine);

        File.AppendAllText(path, insertstatement);
    }
```

Individually, all of them run fine, however if I try to run them in parallel, one completes correctly, and others appear to complete but don't write to their respective files, and a couple of others will fail with the error below - or in serial, the first one runs correctly and the next one fails with

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array:

    at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
       at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
       at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

I believe the issue may be to do with the buffer still containing the previous script component data or something along those lines.

I've spent hours looking for a solution, so any suggestions would be great